# javascript document.getElementById not working

Tags: javascript

Following is my javascript program. I am trying to get all child  tags of parent div tag but when I am running the program document.getElementById('abc') returning null.

```
function init(){
//               currentDiv = document.getElementById("intro");
                alert("working");
                count = 0;
                divs = document.getElementById('abc').getElementsByTagName("div");

                alert("HI " + divs)
                currentDiv = divs[count];
                nextDiv = divs[count + 1]
                count = count + 1;
            }

window.onload = init();
```

Following is my div tag definitions:

```
<div id='abc'> 
<div></div>
</div>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
window.onload = init();
```

You are running `init` and setting the return value as the value of `window.onload`.  My guess is that the code is being executed before the DOM is ready, i.e. before the divs exist.

Try this instead:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) instead, then you have much more powerful tools for this kind of DOM search/traversing

Comment: Jquery is great. But give the people chance to learn how to do things by themselves. This is a good exercise for javascript.

Comment: Agreed - to a point. It's great to learn the basics, but eventually all small projects grow into bigger, and when that time comes you don't want to have too much homegrown basic code.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This should have been a comment.

Comment: @Tomalak: Sometimes I hesitate between making a comment or an answer, this time I decided that it really could be a solution to start using jQuery, so I put it as an answer. Now that I see @lonesomeday:s answer I agree that my answer is more of a comment, but I didn't catch the OP:s real problem and do did not address that. Will try to judge better and better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="init()">
    <div id='abc'> 
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

this probably solves your problem

Comment: Yuk! Keep code out of HTML please. "on*" properties in HTML are _so_ last decade.

Comment: hahahah so what is the differences between <body onload="init()"> and window.onload=init ?

Comment: @savruk - It's just good coding practice.  You don't deserve a downvote, though

Comment: @SidCool well that is what i am saying. they are same. and people must see -at least i think in that way- all the ways to solve a problem. It is not good to stick on only one answer. By the way thanks for upvote

Comment: <body bgcolor=#ffffff text=#000000 link=#0000cc vlink=#551a8b alink=#ff0000 onload="document.f.q.focus();if(document.images)new Image().src='/images/srpr/nav_logo37.png'" >

@Tomalak Geret'kal This is from google main page"(google.nl)" are they so last decade?

Comment: @savruk: Google's HTML is well known for being utterly abysmal, yes.

Comment: @savruk: They're not "the same" at all. That's why the OP had his problem! At the very least, this answer does not explain why the original approach failed, and it does not explain why the `()` are valid in your suggested approach. That's why you got a downvote.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Well it is good to know that I get downwote as i did not explain but not because of the reason in your first comment. This makes sense. So what is the differences between body onload="init()" and window.onload=init?

Comment: "body onload" is an HTML attribute, and it's value is a javascript code snippet. "window.onload" is a JavaScript event handler, and it's value is a function reference. They are two very different ways to reach the same result.

Comment: @savruk: One is in the HTML, the other is in a script. One has parentheses, the other does not (which is because one is inline JS code, whereas the other is a function ref). One is socially deprecated, the other is not. I could go on...

Comment: @savruk: Google's code is optimized for speed, definitely not for readability or cleanliness. That said, they may have a "code optimizer" that interprets the nicely written code their developers write, and converts it into code that is as efficient as possible. Looking at their page source is NOT a good way to learn to code HTML.

Comment: Same result. This is important.That is what I insist on. And that is why my answer use body onload. That is why I said people must see different ways.

Comment: @Peter It was just an example. And i did not suggest to learn html from google source code

Comment: @savruk, your comment "This is from google main page"(google.nl)" are they so last decade?" seemed to me that you wanted to use Google as an example of how it should be done :)

Comment: @Peter i said it because it can be used as a different approach. I did not mean "everybody must use this approach as google use it". absolutely no :). Different way is always better